# Coq rewrite tactic can't find subterm

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I writing a proof in coq and I'm trying to use the `rewrite` tactic. I wanted to include a minimal working example but there are quite a lot of things I would have to include (this proof is building on previous work of my own). Let me know if it is necessary and I can get a working example uploaded. Otherwise:
My current goal is:

```
1 subgoal
A : Type
a : A
h : eq_refl a = eq_refl a
______________________________________(1/1)
eq_refl (eq_refl a) * h * eq_refl (eq_refl a) = h
```

I have defined the notation `*` to be path concatenation (or just using transativity on proofs of equality). Now is where I look to apply `rewrite` on the lhs of the goal equality. I have a path from the term on the lhs to `h * eq_refl` given by `ap(fun (p : eq_refl a = eq_refl a) => p * eq_refl(eq_refl a)) (pinv (refllid h)))` (sorry for the notation, I'm doing HoTT. `ap` takes p : a = b to (ap f p) : f a = f b) for any f). I  can confirm this with `Check`:

```
ap (fun (p : eq_refl = eq_refl) => p * eq_refl) (pinv (refllid h))
     : eq_refl * h * eq_refl = h * eq_refl
```

I also made sure to check that the `eq_refl` s are really `eq_refl (eq_refl a)` by checking things with all implicit arguments printed. But, if I try

```
rewrite (ap(fun (p : eq_refl a = eq_refl a) => p * eq_refl(eq_refl a)) (pinv (refllid h))).
```

I get the error

```
Found no subterm matching "eq_refl * h * eq_refl" in the current goal.
```

But there is quite clearly a subterm of this form. I don't understand why Coq is getting snagged here.

** Edit ** I was able to (laboriously) get the proof to work by using `eq_rect`. But if I'm not mistaken, `rewrite` is based on `eq_rect`. Also I really don't want to have to use `eq_rect` each time. So I'd still love any input on what went wrong with `rewrite`.

Comment: Your equality is of the form `eq_refl * h * eq_refl` but is it with `a`? Like `eq_refl a * h * eq_refl a`. Maybe printing implicit arguments would help see if there is a mismatch.

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter  No, the equality I have is with ```eq_refl (eq_refl a)```. I checked things with all implicit arguments printed to confirm.

Comment: In this case, since you want to rewrite the whole left-hand side of the equality, you could try using transitivity instead (to understand if it unifies there). You could also try to use ssreflect's rewrite to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter Thanks for the idea; ```transitivity``` works. I'll have to look into the ssreflect tactics, I haven't head of those before.

Comment: At this point I have no more ideas, maybe you'd have better luck on coq.zulipchat.com

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter No worries, thanks for the help!